# Kubernetes DNS/service/kubeproxy/configMap vs Netflix ribbon/eureka/cloud config vs AWS ALB/S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, service-discovery

I am new to netflix cloud concepts and AWS and kubernetes and trying to associate the concepts of various technologies and how they relate in terms of each other.

1. Load Balancing-What components does ribbon map to in AWS(ALB?
   although it is server side load balancing) and Kubernetes(Service
   with Kube DNS?)
2. Service Registry-What components does eureka map to in AWS(ALB?) and Kubernetes  (etcd/kubeproxy?)
3. Configuration Management-What components does cloud config server  map to in
   AWS(s3?) and Kubernetes(ConfigMap?)

Answer (score 0):

1. I understand that [Netflix ribbon](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon) is an IPC
   library and there is no such thing in Kubernetes.
   You might be interested in [gRPC](https://grpc.io/) as the part of [CNCF](https://www.cncf.io).
2. In Kubernetes is a registration support for configurable private DNS zones (often called stub domains) and external upstream DNS nameservers.
   The DNS pod is exposed as a Kubernetes Service with a static IP.
3. [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/) command line tool provides command line interface to create [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) for Kubernetes.

For integrating plans Netflix OSP Tools and Kubernetes take a look at:
[kubeflix](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubeflix).

That software components are made for integration Netflix Open Source Platform
Tools with Kubernetes and provides:
Kubernetes Instance Discovery for Turbine and Ribbon and also management for configuration and images for 
Turbine Server and Hystix Dashboard.